# proof Fibonacci and induction

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, fibonacci-numbers

For $ n \ge 1$ ,
$F_1=F_2=1$

for $n \ge 3$ ,$F_n=F_{n-1}+F_{n-2}$

prove that
 $\gcd(F_{n+1},F_n)=1$

I'm trying to prove by induction 
we prove that when $n=1$, the equation holds,
 $\gcd(F_{1},F_1)=1$
next when $n=k$,
suppose  $\gcd(F_{k+1},F_k)=1$ is true, we prove $P(k+1)$ is true using induction hypothesis.

We're trying to prove that $\gcd(F_{k+1+1},F_{k+1})=1$.

We know that $F_{k+2}=F_{k+1}+F_{k}$, does this mean   $\gcd(F_{k+1+1},F_{k+1})=F_k$? 
or  $F_{k+2} =1. F_{k+1} +F_k$?
or $F_{k+2} \equiv  1 \bmod F_{k+1}$?

then
 $$\gcd(F_{k+1+1},F_{k+1})=\gcd(F_{k+1}+F_k,F_{k+1})
=\gcd(F_{k+1},F_{k+2}  \bmod F_{k+1})=\gcd(F_{k+1}+F_{k})=1$$

I'm not too sure about when $F_{k+2}=F_{k+1}+F_{k}$, is this have same meaning as  $\gcd(F_{k+1+1},F_{k+1})=F_k$? or  $F_{k+2} =1. F_{k+1} +F_k$.

Is there an alternative proof?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96121/discussion-on-question-by-fiksx-proof-fibonacci-and-induction).